# Displaying a PDF content in ASP.NET MVC View in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I want to show a PDF in a MVC view. The PDF content comes in form of a base64 string from business layer code. For example

```
string imagestring="Some base64 string";          
Model.ImageData = imagestring;// A string property in model
```

In the view I bind it as

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImageData)" 
type="application/pdf"></object>
```

It works in chrome , displaying the PDF correctly, but in IE 11 it is not displaying. How can I make this code work for IE 11?

Comment: To binding the view I used : <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImageData)" 
    type="application/pdf"></object>

Comment: You have Base64 string from business layer, but you have converted it to Base64 **again** in the view, is this intended?